# I accidentally used `sudo mv /*`

Tags: command-line, filesystem, mv

I have a wordpress site and my current directory was `wp-content`

I just wanted to backup and move the current files of the `wp-content/` folder to a folder called `wp-content-backup20170907` and clone a new `wp-content` folder...

I ran the command

```
sudo mv /*  wp-content-backup20170907
```

And just realised that this moved *everything* - how can I undo this?

Comment: Where you able to fix it?

Comment: Nope no commands were working and now I cannot connect to host :(

Comment: You will need to physically access that host... and do `cd  ~/wp-content-backup20170907`, then do (reverse) `sudo mv wp-content-backup20170907/*    /`. Here I am assuming two things 1) that `wp-content-backup20170907` is in the `/home/$USER` and that you wish to keep your old files else just start a fresh...

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted to do a

```
sudo mv ./* wp-content-backup
```

you moved all files and directories in / partition to your wp-content... directory.

I guess (I never did a mv /* ) you may miss one or many bin executables (including the cp, pwd and mv command ) and also the PATH and configuration files in the shell....

I would try to

1. Move all files and directories back to your / partition

If this doesn't work try #2

2. Try to boot up and mount manually the partitions and move again all the files and directories back to "/" partition.

Comment: thanks. seems to be only these folders remaining mv: cannot move ‘/dev’ to ‘wp-content-backup20170907/dev’: Device or resource busy
mv: cannot move ‘/proc’ to ‘wp-content-backup20170907/proc’: Device or resource busy
mv: cannot move ‘/run’ to ‘wp-content-backup20170907/run’: Device or resource busy
mv: cannot move ‘/sys’ to ‘wp-content-backup20170907/sys’: Device or resource busy
mv: cannot move ‘/var’ to a subdirectory of itself, ‘wp-content-backup20170907/var’

Comment: no commands seem to work..i cannot connect to server now Connection to ec2xxxxxxxx.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com closed by remote host.

Comment: I Assume you don' t have access to the commands because now the directory dont exist ( they were moved ) .

Comment: I def wanted the command sudo mv ./* wp-content-backup... just missed one dot argh.. start all over again

Comment: Hi,  

 this link includes a workaround for this kind of command.   

Ref:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22444699/ubuntu-gone-wrong-because-of-using-mv   

Temporarily, you can do:

PATH=..../backup20170907/folder/usr/bin:.../wp-content-backup20170907/bin:$PATH
"now go to wp-content directory "

cd wp-content-backup20170907/
mv * /

Comment: If previous steps don't work, 

Try using the MV command but this time using the "new path"

Ex. 

# ./backup20170907/folder/bin/mv  backup20170907/* /

Comment: Thanks everyone, I couldn't login to server, so booting another one up . Fortunately I have load balanced environment so am cloning the machine  which is exactly same. Will update shortly. ta

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't login to server, so booting another one up . Fortunately I have load balanced environment so am cloning other machine which is exactly same. This has worked and back to normal, thanks everyone for your suggestions -  if I want still logged in possibly Felipe Gutierrez - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22444699/ubuntu-gone-wrong-because-of-using-mv could of worked. sudo mv ./* wp-content-backup or I think i will use `cp` from now on not `mv`